# Swift - UITextField Programmatically Cannot enter text

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I'm new to Swift programming, I'm trying to build an app with `UITextField` in it, But I'm having a problem, I created an `UITextField` programmatically but it seems like I cannot enter a text in it. Here's my `viewDidLoad`

Code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView = UITableView(frame: self.tableView.frame, style: .Grouped)

    self.groupInfoView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, self.view.frame.width, 100)
    self.groupInfoView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    self.groupInfoView.userInteractionEnabled = true



    groupImg.frame = CGRectMake(10, 50, 40, 40)
    groupImg.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    groupImg.layer.masksToBounds = true
    groupImg.image = UIImage(named: "group-def-img")

    groupTitle = UITextField.init(frame:CGRectMake(groupImg.frame.maxX + 5, 50, self.groupInfoView.frame.width-65, 40))
    groupTitle.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    groupTitle.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    groupTitle.layer.masksToBounds = true
    groupTitle.placeholder = "Enter Group Title"
    groupTitle.textColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    groupTitle.textAlignment = .Center
    groupTitle.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 18)
    groupTitle.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.No
    groupTitle.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.Default
    groupTitle.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done
    groupTitle.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.WhileEditing;
    groupTitle.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.Center
    groupTitle.enabled = true
    groupTitle.userInteractionEnabled = true
    groupTitle.delegate = self
    groupTitle.text = "asda"


    recipientLabel.frame = CGRectMake(5, 0, self.view.frame.width - 20, 40)
    recipientLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 15)
    recipientLabel.numberOfLines = 3
    recipientLabel.textColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    recipientLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    recipientLabel.center.x = self.view.center.x
    recipientLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 7
    recipientLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
    recipientLabel.text = " To:"

    self.groupInfoView.addSubview(groupTitle)
    self.groupInfoView.addSubview(recipientLabel)
    self.groupInfoView.addSubview(groupImg)
    searchBar.delegate = self
    self.titleLabel.text = "New Group Message"
    navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.tabBarController?.tabBar.barStyle = .Black
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.translucent = false
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

    tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 65, bottom: 0, right: 0)

    tableView.registerClass(UserCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleCancel))

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .Done, target: self, action: #selector(handleDone))


    fetchUser()
    self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true

    if let navigationBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar {

        let firstFrame = CGRectMake(0, -5, (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.width)!, 40)
        let secondFrame = CGRectMake(0, 17, (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.width)!, 30)

        titleLabel.frame = firstFrame
        titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-SemiBold", size: 18)
        titleLabel.textAlignment = .Center


        countLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        countLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 13)
        countLabel.frame = secondFrame
        countLabel.textAlignment = .Center

        navigationBar.addSubview(groupInfoView)
        navigationBar.addSubview(titleLabel)
        navigationBar.addSubview(countLabel)

    }

And this is my references:

Code:

var titleLabel = UILabel()
var countLabel = UILabel()
var recipientLabel = UILabel()
var groupImg = UIImageView()
var groupTitle: UITextField = UITextField()
var groupInfoView = UIView()
```

Comment: Does the text field appear? The code you posted doesn't show how/where it is added to a view controller's view.

Comment: Are you seeing any of the output from your delegate methods?

Comment: Yup it appears, I just didn't include the `self.view.addSubview(groupTitle)`

Comment: I'm not seeing any output of my delegate methods.

Comment: are  you declared the <UItextfieddelageate>

Comment: Yes, That is why i can use `groupTitle.delegate = self`

Comment: @TheSurfer try my one its work 100 %

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare its globally so you can access it anywhere. and declare its delegates `UITextFieldDelegate` Headerimageview is my heartimage and HeaderView is my simple header view.

```
@IBOutlet var Headerimageview: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var HeaderView: UIView!
var groupTitle : UITextField = UITextField()
```

In `viewDidLoad()`

```
groupTitle = UITextField.init(frame: CGRectMake(Headerimageview.frame.size.width + 25, 5, self.view.frame.width-85, 40))
groupTitle.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
groupTitle.layer.cornerRadius = 5
groupTitle.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
groupTitle.layer.borderColor = UIColor.brownColor().CGColor
groupTitle.layer.masksToBounds = true
groupTitle.placeholder = "Enter Group Title"
groupTitle.textColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
groupTitle.textAlignment = .Center
groupTitle.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 18)
groupTitle.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.No
groupTitle.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.Default
groupTitle.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done
groupTitle.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.WhileEditing
groupTitle.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.Center
groupTitle.enabled = true
groupTitle.userInteractionEnabled = true
groupTitle.delegate = self
self.HeaderView.addSubview(groupTitle)
```

[image]

Output :

**TextField should begin editing method called**

**TextField did begin editing method called**

**While entering the characters this method gets called**

**While entering the characters this method gets called**

**While entering the characters this method gets called**

**TextField should return method called**

**TextField should snd editing method called**

**TextField did end editing method called**

[image]

**Update your this code with mine one...**

```
 groupTitle = UITextField.init(frame:CGRectMake(groupImg.frame.maxX + 5, 25, self.groupInfoView.frame.width-65, 40))
  groupTitle = UITextField.init(frame: CGRectMake(groupImg.frame.size.width + 25, 25, self.view.frame.width-85, 40))
  self.groupInfoView.addSubview(groupTitle)
  self.groupInfoView.addSubview(groupImg)
  self.view.addSubview(groupInfoView)
```

Comment: Are you able to edit it? Basically mine is on top of `UINavigationBar`

Comment: I mean in side it.

Comment: @TheSurfer did you show me your screen that what you exactly wont.

Comment: replace your code with mine one check output its working completely .

Comment: Basically i have a custom `UIVIew` Below the `UINavigationBar` and inside that `UIView` is the `UITextField`

Comment: then give a frame to your textfield according to your that view and add textfield in your that particular view . are you clear with my answer ?

Comment: I just made little changes check it now @TheSurfer

Comment: I tried this on new project and it's working, The problem in my project is, I'm not using storyboard, all of the items in programmatically created.

Comment: @TheSurfer don't worry i also suggest one for this when you create your Headerview programically at that time you also create your textfiled and add same code that time when your headerview created . so your problem will be solve now

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Hehe but still i have my problem :(

Comment: @TheSurfer Just update your question with Your headerview that you create a programmatically .

Comment: @TheSurfer update your that code with mine one and check result.

Comment: @TheSurfer give me up vote is there your problem solve thank you.